# Query to list orders and return Products

Tags: php, mysql

I need a query to list the products of the budget table but my query lists all the requests but not the associated products within the request.I need help for this,Thanks for helping me.

[Screen image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWAs7.png)

[Model Entity Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcogw.png)

Screen of Program

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Project Web-View Cart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/layoutPrincipal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/formulario.css">
    <style>
 p{
  font-family:"arial black";
  font-size:15px;
  margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
   }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>

<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="../_imagens/Logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="../login.html" target="_self">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<section id="form">
    <?php
 
    session_start();
    $ID_Client = $_SESSION['ID_Client'];

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Error while connecting the database");
    mysql_select_db("Provider",$connection);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $connection);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $connection);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $connection);
 
    $Query= "select order.Service_Status,order.Type_Service,material.Product_Description,material.Amount,material.Unitary_value,material.Amount_Total,budget.Total_Budget from client join order on ClientID_Client='$ID_Client' join budget on ID_Order=OrderID_Order join material on ID_Budget=BudgetID_Budget where ID_Order >0";
    $Result=mysql_query($Query,$connection) or die ("Could not query your data.");
    mysql_close($connection);

 
   while($Query=mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
    
  $Service_Status=$$Query["Service_Status"];     
        $Type_Service=$$Query["Type_Service"];
  $Product_Description=$Query["Product_Description"];
        $Amount=$Query["Amount"];  
  $Unitary_value=$Query["Unitary_value"];
        $Amount_Total=$Query["Amount_Total"];
        $Total_Budget=$Query["Total_Budget"]; 
   
     
    echo "<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Order Details</legend>
 Service Status:$Service_Status<br/>Type Service:$Type_Service<br/><fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>List of Budget</legend>Product Description:$Product_Description<br/>Amount:$Amount<br/>Unitary_value:$Unitary_value<br/>Amount_Total:$Amount_Total<br/>Total_Budget:$Total_Budget</p></fieldset></fieldset>";
  
      }
  
          echo'<fieldset id="form_field">
        <legend id="form_legend">Back</legend>
        <a href="../menuclient.html" id="botao">Back</a>
    </fieldset>';
  
   
  ?>
    

</section>


</body>
</html>
```